# Is there a way to select output video device from browser?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, opentok

I've a live streaming video published using OpenTok. I want to allow user to select a device to display the video published through WebRTC.

Is there any way to select video output devices in browser?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Browsers display video on the page. You can choose [fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) but that's about it I think.

That said, there's a [Presentation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Presentation_API), a sort of "AirPlay for the web" for which seems to [have been implemented](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6676265876586496) in Chrome, and I think maybe Firefox OS.